# BASH: how to perform arithmetic on numbers in a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, math

I am getting a stream of numbers in a pipe, and would like to perform some operations before passing them on to the next section, but I'm a little lost about how I would go about it without breaking the pipe.

for example

```
> echo "1 2 3 4 5" | some command | cat 
1 4 9 16 25
>
```

Would you have any ideas on how to make something like this work? The actual operation I want to perform is simply adding one to every number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5|{
  read line; 
  for i in $line;
  do
    echo -n "$((i * i)) "; 
  done; 
  echo
}
```

The {} creates a grouping.  You could instead create a script for that.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! Exactly what I was looking for. In retrospect, I should have been able to figure this out on my own though :-p

Answer (score 4):

I'd write:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | {
  for N in $(cat); do
    echo $((N ** 2))
  done | xargs
}
```

We can think of it as a "map" (functional programming). There are a lot of ways of writing a "map" function in bash (using stdin, function args, ...), for example:

```
map_stdin() {
  local FUNCTION=$1
  while read LINE; do
    $FUNCTION $LINE
  done
}

square() { echo "$(($1 * $1))"; }

$ echo "1 2 3 4 5" | xargs -n1 | map_stdin square | xargs
1 4 9 16 25
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs -n 1 expr -1 +
```

Comment: This just outputs the 5 numbers for me.

Comment: But notice each is -1 lower, due to `expr -1 +`

Answer (score 4):

Using awk is another solution, which also works with floats

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | xargs -n1 | awk '{print $1^2}' | xargs
```

or use a loop

```
for x in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $((x**2)); done | xargs
for x in $(echo "1 2 3 4 5"); do echo $x^2 | bc; done | xargs # alternative solution
for x in $(seq 5); do python -c "print($x**2)"; done | xargs  # alternative solution but slower than the above
# or make it neat by defining a function to do basic math in bash, e.g.:
calc() { awk "BEGIN{print $*}"; } 
for x in $(seq 5); do calc $x^2; done | xargs
```

Answer (score 3):

Or..

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | xargs -n 1 | while read number 
 do
   echo $((number * number))
 done
```

Comment: Thanks lasseoe. To put it in the middle of the pipe, I'd need to put it in a subshell too. Yours doesn't drop numbers though, which is better!

Comment: Actually, any shell commands in a pipe are automatically run in a subshell; the only reason to put this in `()` would be to group it with a final `echo` as Matthew Flaschen did, and even there you could just as well use `{}` (which do grouping without forcing a subshell).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'echo $(($1*$1))' args
```

Comment: More compact: `seq 5 | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'echo $(($0*$0))'`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can pipe to expression to bc:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | (
  read line; 
  for i in $line;
  do
    echo $i^2 | bc; 
  done; 
  echo
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer Python:

```
#!/bin/python
num = input()
while num:
    print(int(num) + 1) # Whatever manipulation you want
    try:
        num = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

xargs, xargs, xargs

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs -n1 echo | xargs -I NUMBER expr NUMBER \* NUMBER | xargs
```

Or, go parallel:

```
squareit () { expr $1 \* $1; }
export -f squareit
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs -n1 | parallel --gnu squareit | xargs
```

Which would be way simpler if you passed your pipe as a standard set of args:

```
parallel --gnu "expr {} \* {}" ::: $(echo 1 2 3 4 5) | xargs
```

Or even:

```
parallel --gnu "expr {} \* {}" ::: 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs
```

Really worth taking a look at the examples in the doc: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Answer (score -1):

Yoi might like something like this:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | perl -ne 'print $_ ** 2, " " for split / /, $_'
```

or even like this:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | perl -ne 'print join " ", map {$_ ** 2} split / /, $_'
```