# Perform arithmetic on a number in a pipe

Tags: linux, shell, unix, math, pipe

Extremely similar to [BASH: how to perform arithmetic on numbers in a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272215/bash-how-to-perform-arithmetic-on-numbers-in-a-pipe)

However, that answer relates to several numbers and so uses loops, which seems silly as I only have 1 number

`date +%s | echo $((1400000000 - $number)) | ...`

Edit: I plan on passing this command to watch, so using shell expansion will not work correctly... I am aware I could just make it its own script, but I want to know if I can just one-line the whole thing

Answer (score 4):

You can use bc to do arithmetic in the shell.

```
echo "1400000000 - `date +%s`" | bc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $((1400000000 - $(date +%s))) | ...
```

Comment: i plan on passing this command to watch, so using shell expansion isn't an option

Answer (score 0):

I can't do shell expansion, but instead managed to get a variant of John C's answer working:

`date +%s | xargs -I d echo "1400000000 - d" | bc | ...`

There are, of course, several other options