# Executing bash -c with xargs

Tags: bash

I had a job to perform that involved:

- grep lines from a log
- find a number in the line
- perform basic arithmetic on the number (say, number + 1234)

The final result is a bunch of numbers separated by a newline.

If the input was:

```
1000
2000
3000
```

Then the required output was:

```
2234
3234
4234
```

I ended up with the following command:

```
cat log.txt | grep "word" | cut -d'|' -f7 | cut -d' ' -f5 | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'echo $(($1 + 1234))' args
```

I found the `xargs -n 1 bash -c 'echo $(($1 + 1234))' args` snippet in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272215/bash-how-to-perform-arithmetic-on-numbers-in-a-pipe) but I don't understand the need for the final `args` argument that is passed in. I can change it to anything, `args` could be `blah`, but if I omit it the arithmetic fails and the output is the numbers unchanged:

```
1000
2000
3000
```

Could anyone shed some light on why `args` is a required argument to `bash -c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man bash:

> -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments  after
>                    the command_string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

So, for your case, 'args' is a placeholder that goes in `$0`, making your actual input go in `$1`.

You should be able to alter your command to:

```
grep "word" log.txt | cut -d'|' -f7 | cut -d' ' -f5 | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'echo $(($0 + 1234))'
```

Comment: You are indeed correct. I read the man page but didn't grok the explanation. If I replace `$1` with `$0` and remove the `args` argument, then the command works as expected. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

A simple `awk` command can do the same - in a clean way:

```
awk -F'|' '/word/{split($7,a," "); print a[5]+1234}' log.txt
```

Comment: `awk` is on my todo list! I was reading this recently, https://gregable.com/2010/09/why-you-should-know-just-little-awk.html

Comment: Much more elegant ;)